# Object spawning into anther object's border

Tags: c++, ncurses

I created a simple game using ncurses library and C++. Main idea is that a player, which is a yellow square, is walking on the board and collect as much "*" as possible. It mustn't crash into the obstacles and borders also. At the start, there are 100 of them spawned and after collecting one, another one is spawned on random positions. My problem is given: Before spawning asterisks, I am checking the coordinates of the obstacles in order to avoid asterisk spawning inside the obstacle. It works most of the time, but there are some very rare cases when asterisk is spawned inside the obstacle. Do I have any logical bug? Or am I doing something incorrectly? What is an alternative of my solution?

These is data about obstacles

```
    mainwin = initscr();
    obscatle=subwin(mainwin,7,2,1,6);
    obscatle2=subwin(mainwin,10,2,8,20);
    obscatle3=subwin(mainwin,2,2,17,50);
    obscatle4=subwin(mainwin,6,2,25,70);
    obscatle5=subwin(mainwin,12,2,10,90);
    obscatle6=subwin(mainwin,20,2,8,110);
    obscatle7=subwin(mainwin,22,2,4,130);
    obscatle8=subwin(mainwin,17,2,18,150);
```

These are the functions.

```
//At the start of the game, spawn asterisks on random positions
vector<pair<int,int>> generate_asterisk(int numberOfLines, int numberOfColumns) {
    vector<pair<int,int>> coordinates;
    srand(time(0)); 
    while(coordinates.size() < 500) {
        int x = (rand() % (COLS - 3)) + 1;
        int y = (rand() % (LINES - 5)) +1;

        // Check if x and y match the given values, and generate new random values until they don't match
        while((y >= 1 && y <= 7 && (x >= 5 && x <= 9)) ||
               (y >= 8 && y <= 17 && (x >= 19 && x <= 23)) ||
               (y >= 17 && y <= 18 && (x >= 49 && x <= 53)) ||
               (y >= 25 && y <= 30 && (x >= 69 && x <= 73)) ||
               (y >= 10 && y <= 21 && (x >= 89 && x <= 93)) ||
               (y >= 8 && y <= 27 && (x >= 109 && x <= 114)) ||
               (y >= 4 && y <= 25 && (x >= 129 && x <= 134)) ||
               (y >= 18 && y <= 34 && (x >= 149 && x <= 154))) {
            x = (rand() % (COLS - 3)) + 1;
            y = (rand() % (LINES - 5)) + 1;
        }

        pair<int,int> coord = make_pair(x,y);
        if(find(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end(), coord) == coordinates.end()) {
            coordinates.push_back(coord);
        }
    }
    return coordinates;
}



//after collecting, spawn a new one
void spawnAsterisk(WINDOW* win, int x_max, int y_max, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& asterisk_coords)
{
    // Generate new coordinates for the asterisk
        int new_x = (rand() % (COLS - 3)) + 1;
        int new_y = (rand() % (LINES - 5)) +1;

        while((new_y >= 1 && new_y <= 7 && (new_x >= 5 && new_x <= 9)) ||
               (new_y >= 8 && new_y <= 17 && (new_x >= 19 && new_x <= 23)) ||
               (new_y >= 17 && new_y <= 18 && (new_x >= 49 && new_x <= 53)) ||
               (new_y >= 25 && new_y <= 30 && (new_x >= 69 && new_x <= 73)) ||
               (new_y >= 10 && new_y <= 21 && (new_x >= 89 && new_x <= 93)) ||
               (new_y >= 8 && new_y <= 27 && (new_x >= 109 && new_x <= 114)) ||
               (new_y >= 4 && new_y <= 25 && (new_x >= 129 && new_x <= 134)) ||
               (new_y >= 18 && new_y <= 34 && (new_x >= 149 && new_x <= 154))) {
            new_x = (rand() % (COLS - 3)) + 1;
            new_y = (rand() % (LINES - 5)) + 1;
        }
    // Check if the new coordinates conflict with existing asterisks
    bool conflict = false;
    for (const auto& coord : asterisk_coords)
    {
        if (coord.first == new_x && coord.second == new_y)
        {
            conflict = true;
            break;
        }
 
         
    }

    // If there's a conflict, generate new coordinates until there's no conflict
    while (conflict)
    {
        new_x = rand() % x_max;
        new_y = rand() % y_max;

        conflict = false;
        for (const auto& coord : asterisk_coords)
        {
            if (coord.first == new_x && coord.second == new_y)
            {
                conflict = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    asterisk_coords.push_back(std::make_pair(new_x, new_y));

    mvwprintw(win, new_y, new_x, "*");
    wrefresh(win);
}
```

I am checking manually, because this is my level right now. I tried this and since it works in most of the time, I think I am close to the answer. Or maybe the code is correct but the error is because of the screen size.

Comment: First of all, remove all code duplication, especially one related to obstacles. Put them in vector and work with this vector everywhere. Otherwise nobody could guarantee that your coordinates in subwin calls and while checks correspond. Actually, you could draw one set of obstacles and check against another one.

Comment: The fragment isn't [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like you could use two functions: 1) Verify a coordinate is on the board.  2) Verify a coordinate is not an obstacle.  These would make your code simpler and more easy to read.  Maybe have a `std::vector<Coordinate> obstacles` and pass it around your functions (by reference).